Is this the correct Dual for this Linear program? why?
The following LP appears in the paper introducing polyamorous scheduling (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2403.00465 pages 30 and 31, equations 5 to 8)
max $l$
s.t.
$\sum_{m\in M} y_m \leq 1$
$\sum_{m\in M:e\in m}\frac{y_m}{g_e}\geq l \quad \forall e\in R$
$y_m \geq 0 \qquad \forall m\in M$
The following is also given as the dual for the above LP (equations 9 to 12):
min $x$
s.t.
$\sum_{e\in R} z_e \geq 1$
$\sum_{e\in m}\frac{z_e}{g_e}\leq x \quad \forall m\in M$
$z_e \geq 0 \qquad \forall e\in R$.
I'm trying to confirm the correctness of this and gain a better understanding for this result. I'm studying this paper as a part of my PhD studies, but I have a limited background in formal mathematics.
my main line of reasoning has been to try to convert the LP and Dual into standard form, as given in sources like these notes (https://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs261/lecture06.pdf page 4), but am struggling to find a form that adds up for several reasons:
$\textbf{c}^T\textbf{y} = l$,
while
$\textbf{y}\geq 0$ is broadly analogous to $y_m \geq 0 \qquad \forall m\in M$,
which seems to only be possible if rows are missing, presumably because $l\geq 0$ is considered obvious and of $\textbf{c}^T_i = 0 \quad\forall i:i\geq 1$
